# how to decelerate small probes in space?

Tags: space

How could I decelerate a probe in space?

I'm working on a world in an alternate near future, the first part would be (small) asteroid mining probes at ~3 Astronomic Units distance.

No organic life forms on board, just machines.

Launched via slingshots, or mass drivers from earth orbit, or the moon (cost efficient, low fuel).  After that, maybe laser/particle beam and solar sail, or rocket propulsion.

The problem is, how can I decelerate in a cost-efficient manner?

Would something like solar sails and laser/particle beam(s) projected from near their destination viable?
Are there any better options?
The destination would be the asteroid belt, not Mars, so there's not one destination point with established infrastructure, unlike the launch point.

edit: maybe some mobile infrastructure
like catch and refuel 1000 probes ,then move to next sector

Edit:
Is it possible to store kinetic energy of an probe in a kind of magnetic spring?
(i mean harvest  the energy from kinetic back to electric)

A kind of reverse railgun(or gauss cannon?) - a long tunnel with inductive coils that "catches" the probe.

Edit 2:
The technology level is current era + 50 years, so a little beyond Next Tuesday.

In my alternate world, there was no 2001 crash, no 2008 crash, no pandemic, and no stupid wars, most nations working together cooperatively, but some limited competition to get new resources
(maybe small corporate conflicts).

Maybe early fusion power plants, and expansion infrastructure already built in space or on the Moon.

Comment: You can't ask a hard science question about a cost optimization without giving any information on the cost structure of your society. Is it more cost efficient to have a horse or a car? has a different answer if you ask it in the early 1900 or in the early 2000.

Comment: (1) What does 3AE mean? (2) The most propellant-efficient way to slow down a probe is [lithobraking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithobraking), obviously. Cannot get better propellant efficiency than zero propellant expended. If lithobraking is not the correct answer, why is that? Is something missing from the question?

Comment: You are overthinking this way to much. How do you decelerate in space ? Use an engine, an Ion thruster, something chemical or nuclear ?

Comment: are there limits for lithobraking? I mean, what is the max speed or kinetic energy, if I would like to farm an asteroid and not vaporize it and the probe

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "store kinetic energy of a probe". Sure, you could compress a spring on board the probe, but that's not going to affect its flight path.

Comment: "Catching" something with magnetic induction coils is totally feasible and the basis of a space fountain, but seems at odds with your statement making it clear that these probes would have many destinations and would not have centralized infrastructure.   Voting to close until more details are provided per other comments.

Comment: Propel the probe to its destination via laser-sail. Then, shoot a mirror out in front of the probe, then re-aim the laser to reflect off it towards a sail on the probe's front.

Comment: @ErikHall is ion engine not too weak? it is good for accelerating for looong distances and lightweight probes. maybe "small" explosion brake would be better

Comment: @jdunlop what information  do you need?
I think "moving"  infrastructure would be possible
at least refuelling, some power plants and transport and something for deccelerating

how accurate are current satelite aiming?
is it possible to fly motorcycle sized probe through some container sized rings with an speed of ~30 lightminutes per week(not sure if it is realistic at that techstage, just a starting number)

Comment: @Krumpel - if you have the energy budget to move your catchers' mitt all over the asteroid belt, you're better off using that energy to decelerate the probes.  It's difficult to imagine a setup where you wouldn't come out worse in the energy equation by moving the infrastructure.  And we hit a 100m-wide object with a 600kg object back in 2021.  30 lightminutes/week is kind of nuts, though.  That's into fractional-c range, and, I would argue, unnecessarily fast for inner-system travel.  It'd also require 238 terajoules to get going, or 66 GWh.

Comment: (As an additional aside, if you have the energy to move a "catcher's mitt" all over the asteroid belt, why not just have it be a mobile factory that processes mineral wealth and fires it in-system, avoiding the need to launch probes in the first place?)

Comment: @Krumpel Acceleration = Deceleration. If you have the time an ion drive works perfectly fine.

Comment: I think "random" asteroid farming on the beld make less sense than sending several drones to one location, have the infrastructure there, or build it, then move to next.
 30 lightminutes/week is not so nuts, it is just ~67 days with an 500MW power plant... sure, lower speed make more sense, or some kind of engine on the probe. what is a "good" mass and distance for ion enginge? I saw only lightweight . I would like to have something that is faster than 3 months to mars(I think the numbers were for fusion/fission(?) drive manned mission)

Comment: @Krumpel - a reminder that a 500 MW power plant takes up four acres of land and powers fifty thousand households.  There's nothing "just" about using that for sixty seven continuous days just to make _one_ probe a bit speedier on its way to the asteroid belt - plus, of course, at 30 lightminutes/week, it would only take a week to _get_ to the belt, so you'd be consuming 67 days of a utility-scale power plant to fling something the size of a motorcycle slightly faster.  It's effectively a mining barge; let it travel slowly!

Comment: thanks a lot, I think the thread can be closed now. I read tons of pdfs last days and viewed few hours about space mining. I think I have to rewrite my world, the deceleration is not the problem, I think mining will start earlier than I thoght an with lower tech. mass driver would be nice, but I think centralized expansion makes more sense. Orbit->Moon->Mars->Ceres->random asteroids. the last hops could have an mass driver for single probes, but the stations before make more sense with sending bunch of drones and bigger infrastructure